# Create connection from RabbitMQ to ActiveMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, activemq-classic, cloudamqp

I have details of a ActiveMQ server which i would like to connect to and view the data availble. I would like to use RabbitMQ(CloudAMQP).

I have read the documentation, but I cant work out how to make this connection?

The connection details I have are as follows:

```
host = 'ssl://api.myreports.com:61613'
user='myuser'
password='mypassword'
topicname = '/topic/myTopic'
```

As far as I am aware these are sufficient details to connect.
Any help is very welcome.

Comment: Are you trying to use a RabbitMQ client to connect to ActiveMQ or are you trying to create some sort of network connection between two brokers?

Comment: Hi, trying to create a network connection between two brokers.

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't work for a number of reasons chief of which is that broker networks typically require that the brokers be the same in order for them to manage the network connection traffic using built in logic.  Also ActiveMQ only supports broker networks using its own protocol (OpenWire) and not AMQP at the broker network layer.

You could try using something like Apache Camel to create a bridge between the two brokers to allow message traffic pass between the two.  The solution will depend a lot on your use case.